# kafka streams | switch to different cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a requirement where I have to switch the kafka streams which is connected to kafka-cluster-1 to kafka-cluster-2 based on a criteria. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Steams is limited to one cluster.

If you change bootstrap servers, all internal topic state will be lost and you'll need to recreate your input topic(s)

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must do so, you should use MirrorMaker2 (or Confluent Replicator) to replicate the topics (input,output, **and changelog**) from the cluster-1 to cluster-2. But you'll have downtime. The workflow is as follows:

1. Create topics with the same name as the input topics in cluster-2 and configure producers to start producing to cluster-2.
2. Once the Kafka Stream cluster in cluster-1 is idle (caught up), terminate it.
3. User MirrorMaker2 to replicate the changelog and output topics to cluster-2.
4. Once the changelog and output topics are fully replicated, then you can restart your Kafka Streams cluster in cluster-2 (do NOT use the same disks, otherwise, the checkpoint offset will be messed up).
5. Once the Kafka Streams cluster has restored its state from the changelog, then it will start processing again.

Be careful that the topic names are identical—if there is a prefix/suffix added in the replicated cluster, you'll have to spin up a producer/consumer to copy the data over into a topic with the exact same name.